# Cassandra Column Family latency

Tags: performance, cassandra, monitoring, latency

I have a single Node Cassandra setup (12 GB Ram, 2x Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5550  @ 2.67GHz) with a cron, running every 10 minutes. The cron issues ~500 writes to the node each time it runs.

Cron activity is seen in the cassandra monitoring as peaks and cpu load on the mashine.

[image]

[image]

I have no experience with cassandra clusters / monitoring - what is a "good" value from column latencies and would you expect to see such peaks with the given number of writes to the cluster?

Comment: what units is latency in? micro or milli?

Comment: To be honest i cant even tell you. The query is Graphana is: sum(irate(cassandra_columnfamily_writelatency{instance="$instance"}[5m]))  .I played with the cassandra-stress tool and saw latencies around 40ms and 100ms max. The dashboard above was showing a value of ~ 4k at this moment.